# How to install pivot_long() and pivot_wide() in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, spread

If you want to try these new functions (`pivot_wide` and `pivot long`), you need to install the development version of `tidyr`:

`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")`.

But I have not managed to achieved it. I install a list of libraries except one, ( `vctrs`) and I don't know if that's the problem.

When I run the next code:

```
  mtcars_wide1 <- mtcars %>%
  pivot_wide(names_from = "am",
             values_from = "mpg")
```

R couldn't find the function.

[image]

Can you recommend me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the **lasted version of R** installed - the latest is currently 3.6.1.

```
R.version
```

I had the same problem as you, but I [updated](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-step-by-step-screenshots-tutorial-for-upgrading-r-on-windows/)  R, reinstalled the dev version of the tidyverse

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse")
```

…and all was good. Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 2):

It seems they changed their names to pivot_wider and pivot_longer:

https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/579

Answer (score 2):

`pivot_longer()` is from the package `tidyr`, so make sure it's installed and loaded:

```
install.packages("tidyr")
library(tidyr)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, they changed the names to `pivot_wider()` and `pivot_longer()`. You need to change the function names in your code to these.

Second, these are now integrated into CRAN for `tidyverse` and you don't need the development version. If your R is already an updated version all you need to do is update the version of `tidyverse` by reinstalling it. Just run the code:

`install.packages('tidyverse')`

Or if you want to update all of your packages in R you can simply run:

`update.packages()`

This will take care of updating `tidyverse` and is in fact what I used and what worked for me after changing my code to `pivot_wider()`.