# How to calculate transition probabilities in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to calculate how often changes between values happen by person-year combination (panel data). This mimics Stata's command `xttrans`. The transition between index 6 and 7 should not be included, since it is not a transition from within one person.

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                year=seq(from=2003, to=2009, by=1), 
                health=c(3,1,2,2,5,1,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Calculate the last health status for each id
df <- df %>% 
         group_by(id) %>% 
         mutate(lastHealth=lag(health)) %>%  
         ungroup()
# Count nunmber of existing transitions
transitions <- df %>% 
                  group_by(health, lastHealth) %>%  
                  summarise(N=n()) %>% 
                  ungroup()
# Fill in the transition grid to include possible transitions that weren't observed
transitions <- transitions %>% 
                 complete(health=1:5, lastHealth=1:5, fill=list(N=0))
# Present the transitions in the required format
transitions %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="health", values_from="N", names_prefix="health") %>%
  filter(!is.na(lastHealth))
```

Comment: I cannot use `pivot_wider`. Figuring out the reasons related to old R versions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534005/how-to-install-pivot-long-and-pivot-wide-in-r

Comment: Yes.  `pivot_wider` is relatively new.  In older versions, the function was `spread`.  In this simple case, the conversion should be straightforward, but let me know if you can't figure it out. I'll provide an alternative.  [You're happy with everything up to that point though?]

Comment: I working on adjusting everything to the n-dimensional case including potential NA.

Comment: I believe my code handles `NA` in `health` already.  If not, let me know.  If by multidimensional you mean "more group variables than just `id`", then modify the two `group_by`s to include the additional variables in front of what's there now.  if you have more state categories than `1:5`, modify the two `1:5`s in `complete()` accordingly.

Comment: It works :) I actually only need to create transitions. The pivot_wider makes the table more readable, but it can also be read rowwise.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R solution to calculate transition counts by `id` groups:

```
with(df, do.call(`+`, tapply(health, id, function(x){
  x <- factor(x, levels = min(health, na.rm = T):max(health, na.rm = T))
  table(x[-length(x)], x[-1])
})))

#    1 2 3 4 5
#  1 2 3 0 0 0
#  2 1 1 1 0 1
#  3 1 1 0 0 0
#  4 0 0 0 0 0
#  5 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I'm trying to adjust the code. The issue is in my real data I have a unbalanced data. Different numbers of occurances and lots of NA.

Comment: @MarcoDoe My code can deal with unbalanced data. As for NAs, you don't provide example so I'm not sure  about the real situation.

Comment: `min()` and `max()` throw errors if for some person I don't have health data. I'm sorry to not be clearer when creating the MWE.